# Google Sitemap XML isn't showing About Page, Contact Page, Etc, only

Tags: google-search-console, wordpress, robots.txt, xml-sitemap

My google sitemap has been uploaded to Google Search Console using `example.com/sitemap_index.xml`
When I click to the page in google search console 'sitemaps read:' I can only see the following:

- `example.com/author-sitemap.xml`
- `example.com/category-sitemap.xml`
- `example.com/e-landing-page-sitemap.xml`
- `example.com/page-sitemap.xml`
- `example.com/post-sitemap.xml`

The actual pages my site consists of are:

- `example.com/about`
- `example.com/work`
- `example.com/services`
- `example.com/contact`

Should the about/work/services pages be listed in Google Search Console when I click into the `sitemap_index.xml` file? Or have I done the XML file incorrectly?

I am using a Child Theme on Elementor on Wordpress.
The only thing in my robots.txt file is the following:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
```

I do have a devoted page `example.com/sitemap` with all my pages listed out

[image: my active sitemap on Google Search Console]

Comment: It sounds like `/about`, `/work`, etc are listed in the `page-sitemap.xml`, correct?

Comment: Are you using Yoast to generate your XML sitemaps?

Comment: Correct I am using Yoast.
Yes the about and work are listed in the page-sitemap.xml - but does that impact Google's ease of being able to find this and the benefits for SEO?

Comment: There are almost no SEO benefits from XML sitemaps.   At best they direct Googlebot to crawl all your pages.  However for most sites, that would happen even without a sitemap, especially for small sites like yours.   Search engines don't usually choose to index pages just because they are in a sitemap, nor do sitemaps help with rankings.  See [SEO Myth: An XML sitemap is needed for SEO; it helps rankings](https://blog.ostermiller.org/xml-sitemap-rankings/)

Comment: Ok thank you so much! I couldn't google it anywhere if I was setting it up correctly or if I was missing a step